# SQL: Updating 2 different columns in table from CTE condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

Hi I have a temp table with 2 different columns that I am trying to update from a CTE that has a boolean column 'uninstalled'. As in:

```
--Temp table to be updated:

CREATE TABLE temp_customers (
report_date date,
app_installed bigint,
app_uninstalled bigint,
total_volume bigint,
);

--CTE to be used to update the temp table:

with CTE as (
select count(account_id) as total_accounts
from customer_account ca
where uninstalled = false
);
```

I then want to update the table 'temp_customers' above from the CTE and their respective columns (where uninstalled = true shall update column 'app_uninstalled' with the correct volume of accounts and where uninstalled = false from CTE should only update column 'app_installed' with its respective volume.) How can I create this unique update statement for the 'temp_customers' including the report_date as the current timestamp?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Please start with the problem to be solved (what you are trying to achieve). You probably don't need a CTE. And you might not need a temp table either. And always disclose your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_customers AS
SELECT current_date                                AS report_date
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE uninstalled = false) AS app_installed
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE uninstalled        ) AS app_uninstalled
     , count(*)                                    AS total_volume
FROM   customer_account;
```

No CTE, no `UPDATE`.
Depending on what you plan to do with the result you might not need the temp table, either ...

Comment: Hi Erwin thank you for this. I have this request to pull this table that will check the volume of customers that is using this app on a daily basis. I need the SQL query to return the volume of customers for 5 different scenarios (e.g. new customers, active customers, etc) against the volume of customers that either installed or uninstalled the app - hence why the installed / uninstalled columns in my question. The query you helped me with is just one of the 5 scenarios to be checked against the volume of installed/uninstalled. Out of interest how would you go about creating this final table?

Comment: @ERR: Chances are, you can compute all numbers in a single `SELECT` and return results directly, without the overhead of a temp table. I would need the *exact*  setup and *exact* requirements to say more. You might start a new question - and be a lot more specific than for this one.